# tlmgr: install package in old distro gives checksum error

Tags: texlive, tlmgr

Texlive 2020 (one year old, I know):

I try to install a package for tl2020, but the installation fails:

```
tlmgr install pgfplots
tlmgr: package repository https://ctan.net/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: valid signature with expired key)
[1/1, ??:??/??:??] install: pgfplots [14898k]
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove: checksums differ for /var/folders/md/l2nnr5490tq114003qtxfnk40000gn/T/Kgox3_SlKE/2mUVrNHss6/pgfplots.tar.xz:
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove:   tlchecksum=8f4661e193d6b2d9a5e3f488ff7f35849fe559fe4587b5050ac67256aa4b93e24c79948e8f8757eb901e6b531fffffd6597049b1e457d79db36d5043f00e10e5, arg=65364a44b5950ece4c6b6797b149a147dce134f89e2d9402d9a42e656c4a1170c23cc66c8357599addb8283617061850247d9d679fa2ebdd2ffa90b311492b6c
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove: backtrace:
 -> /opt/texlive2020/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm:2342: TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove
 -> /opt/texlive2020/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1976: TeXLive::TLUtils::unpack
 -> /opt/texlive2020/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1811: TeXLive::TLPDB::_install_data
 -> /opt/texlive2020/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1727: TeXLive::TLPDB::not_virtual_install_package
 -> /opt/texlive2020/bin/x86_64-darwin/tlmgr:3855: TeXLive::TLPDB::install_package
 -> /opt/texlive2020/bin/x86_64-darwin/tlmgr:794: main::action_install
 -> /opt/texlive2020/bin/x86_64-darwin/tlmgr:706: main::execute_action
 -> /opt/texlive2020/bin/x86_64-darwin/tlmgr:377: main::main
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove:   removing /var/folders/md/l2nnr5490tq114003qtxfnk40000gn/T/Kgox3_SlKE/2mUVrNHss6/pgfplots.tar.xz, but saving copy in /var/folders/md/l2nnr5490tq114003qtxfnk40000gn/T/lhXCcVTc1x
TLPDB::_install_data: downloading did not succeed (check_file_and_remove failed) for https://ctan.net/systems/texlive/tlnet/archive/pgfplots.tar.xz
tlmgr: package log updated: /opt/texlive2020/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log
```

Other packages install correctly. Any idea what I can do?

I've tried with

```
no-checksums = 1
```

in the config file, but I can't see that this has any effect.

Comment: I would have expected all usages just stopped with a warning that your local repository was too old, ctan doesn't hold live updates for old texlive.

Comment: Holy Cow! Isn't there an 'A' in CTAN? Or a 'C'? What do these letters stand for? Outdating a one year old software is so bloody *****.

Anyhow, thank you David for your answer.

Comment: @topskip That has nothing to to with CTAN.

Comment: it's a texlive rather than ctan decision, they just don't have the resources to update/maintain multiple releases so once it rolls over a year you can't update (although you can grab the snapshot of the "final" texlive 2020. CTAN has never held multiple versions of anything, if you update a package on ctan then it over-writes the old one.

Comment: @daleif OK, I stand corrected. Thanks

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I still wonder why the `no-checksums = 1` does not work...

Comment: yes the errors you show are not expected, even if I wouldn't expect it to work....